# Button image Xamarin.forms

Tags: image, button, xamarin.forms

The `Image Source="icons.png"` works fine
but when i insert this code: `Button Image="icons.png"`
the App won't display in the Xamarin live

This is my code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="Project.CustomImages">
        <StackLayout>
        <Button Image="icons.png"/>
        <Label Text="TEST"/>
            <Image Source="icons.png"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

This is the screen shot of `Recources/drawable`:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsgbL.png)

Comment: <Button x:Name="someButton"/> and from code behind try something like this: someButton.Image = ImageSource.FromFile("icons.png");

Comment: You can also refer this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21301/image-property-on-the-button

Answer (score 0):

Try to place an image instead of button.

You can make use of Tap Gesture Recogniser to take click events.

Try something like this :

```
<Image Source="icons.jpg">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="OnTapped"  />
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

The code for the event handler

```
void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    // Do something
    DisplayAlert ("Alert", "Image Button Clicked", "OK");
}
```